# Visual Studio Codeで言語ごとにインデントの設定をしたい

Tags: vscode

Visual Studio CodeにてHTML、JavaScriptはタブスペース2、Pythonでは4といったようにファイル種別ごとに設定を行うことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Language specific editor settings - Visual Studio Code User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)で紹介されている言語ごとのエディタ構成からタブスペースサイズをそれぞれ指定すれば可能かと思います。

1. Ctrl+Shift+Pで開くコマンドパレットに`Preferences: Configure language specific settings`を入力/選択してユーザー用設定を開く。
2. 編集対象の言語を入力/選択する。
3. スペースサイズは`editor.tabSize`プロパティから設定できます。

参考:

```
{
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    }
}
```